# Android how to make app searchable from Finder?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-fragments

I want my app to be searchable from phone's quick Finder using a keyword.
As you can see in the picture, i searched for 'navigate' and it showing me apps related to that even though it does not contain 'navigate' in app name

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Android, but on iOS there is [this package (flutter_siri_suggestion)](https://github.com/myriky/flutter_siri_suggestions)